# Using local file instead of $.getJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, highcharts

I'm very new to Javascript so apologies in advanced.

This [link](http://jsfiddle.net/bsHM8/) contains a charts data from a file named `jsonp.php` using an AJAX request.

I'm attempting to recreate this but use a local file instead of the one from their server. I can download their example `jsonp.php` file and save it to my desktop.

I've managed to put together this code which allows me to open and read the file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<input type="file" id="files" name="file" />
<div id="container" style="height: 500px; min-width: 500px"></div>?

<script>
function handleFileSelect(evt)
{
    var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++)
    {

        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = (function(reader)
        {
            return function()
            {
                var contents = reader.result;
                //var lines = contents.split('\n');
                //example('test')
                //////
                //document.getElementById('container').innerHTML=contents;
            }
        })(reader);

        reader.readAsText(f);
    }
}

//function example(a)
//{
//alert('You have chosen: ' + a);
//}

document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
</script>
</html>
```

I'm now trying to combine both scripts to show the charts with the local file (see [link](http://jsfiddle.net/bsHM8/1/)). I've tried to remove the ajax call and call the function with `renderChart(f)`

```
function renderChart(data) {
    // Create the chart
    window.chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
        chart : {
            renderTo : 'container'
        },

        rangeSelector : {
            selected : 1
        },

        title : {
            text : 'AAPL Stock Price'
        },

        series : [{
            name : 'AAPL',
            data : data,
            tooltip: {
                valueDecimals: 2
            }
        }]
    });
});
```

which isn't working. Please can I ask where I'm going wrong

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were several syntax errors in the JSFiddle you sent. [Here is a new JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S4C5a/) with the basic errors resolved. However I did not try to use a file formatted as Highcharts should need it.

Hint: try using the Javascript Console in Chrome to see the errors.

Comment: Thanks for that. It is now rendering the chart but the data is not being read. I've tried sending the contents instead using `var contents = reader.result;` then `renderChart(contents);` which again isn't working? Any ideas why the saved jsonp.php is different to the one received from $.getJSON?